# Firestore security rules to compare two databases and prevent duplication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my app I want to be able to have books assigned to a reader without there being any duplicates. Can I assign a rule like that to firestore or is that something to handle in my swiftui code? The security rules so far is as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
     match/users/{uid}{
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid
        allow create
     }
    
     match/books/{id}{//display library if user logged in
      allow read: if request.auth != null
    }
    
  
    match/reader/{uid}{//check for readers assigned to user
    
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid; 
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
      match/reader_books/{id}{
       allow read: if request.auth != null
       allow write:if request.auth != null
      }
  
    }
    
   
  }
}
```

EDIT: I tried to create a function in swiftui code to check for duplicates here:

```
   func checkData(_ readerBooks: ReaderBooks){
    
    print("reader ID : \(readerBooks.readerID)")
    let checkBooks = db.collection("reader_books").document("\(readerBooks.readerID)")
 
    checkBooks.getDocument{(document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists{
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        }else{
            print("Document does not exist")
            self.postData(readerBooks)
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to add a book to a reader it always returns document does not exist in the console even when the readerID is present in the document's field. Is there an issue with the code somewhere?

Comment: Please be more clear - are you saying that a book should have only ever have one reader, or that a book may only appear in a reader's reader_books subcollection only once?

Comment: A reader should not have two of the same book

Answer (score 0):

You don't need security rules for this.  In the reader_books subcollection, just use the same ID as the book from the books collection.  Since a collection can't have two documents with the same ID, it will be impossible for one book to appear in that collection twice.

Comment: So I should make changes to the swiftui code to check for duplicates and not the firestore security rules? Is the ID I should be using the documentID?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: How do I change the documentID into the readerID I want in the swiftui code?